# Java to JavaScript (JSON): how to restore connections by reference?

Tags: javascript, java, json, pass-by-reference

From Java I'm returning a few Objects in a 
    Map>>
in a REST endpoint for the front-end.

The important thing to consider here is that the same MyObject may be present in different positions, hence updating one Object updates all its occurrences.

I needed to restore those connections by reference among all the occurrences of a MyObject in TypeScript.
I can distinguish all the occurrences of a MyObject by their IDs.
So I'm currently replacing all the occurrences of a MyObject with its first one, previously persisted in a map by ID. This way I'able to restore the connections by reference among all the occurrences of the same MyObject.

My solution seems to be ok, but I'm still wondering if I'm not reinventing the wheel. Is there any alternative way, possibly better than mine, of achieving this goal?

Comment: Why downvoting? Please explain. Don't you think this would be a great information to keep?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're serializing the object from Java to JSON over the REST service.

By the time the object is received by the client in TypeScript, it is going to treat each of those objects as separate.  That's the nature of sending it out across the wire... every basically written out as a string and things like memory addresses of individual objects are moot at that point.

I'm not sure there's much more you could do beyond what you are already doing by replacing all equal objects with your one singleton per each.

To be honest, it sounds like a pretty unique use-case.

Comment: Yes, as I was thinking. However I think it would be a great feature if each object had an extra field for the memory address after serialization, in order to allow restoring the connections by reference automatically during deserialization.

Comment: In addition, by using just the memory address for all the occurrences other than first, it would also reduce the size of the JSON to be transported.

Comment: Memory addresses are dependent on many things.  The operating system type, the programming language one is working in, etc.  It's not necessarily something that translates from one machine to another.  And one of the main ideas of a standards-based interchange such as REST (JSON over HTTP) is that it removes those system-specific dependencies.  This makes it possible for anyone to use the REST endpoint regardless of their specific implementation matching the server's implementation.

Comment: Yes, that's fine to abstract from the single machine layer. I didn't explain myself well when talking about memery-address. For "memory address" I meant a unique identifier to distinguish among all the occurrences of the same object (e.g. I think the hashcode of the object would be enough).

Comment: Not necessarily the Java method, e.g. SHA 3 512 hash of the JSON corresponding to that object.